# How can I change the path in VS Code to the extension and what is the correct path to autopep8 if I already installed the python extension?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autopep8

I receive this error when trying to install module "`autopep8`" for VS Code:

```
rrgut@DESKTOP-NQJ4S14 MINGW64 ~/Documents/Raymond/HelloWorld
$ C:/Users/rrgut/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:\Users\rrgut\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.114305\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U autopep8 --user
C:\Users\rrgut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\rrgut\Documents\Raymond\HelloWorld\Usersrrgut.vscodeextensionsms-python.python-2020.9.114305pythonFilespyvsc-run-isolated.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: run the `pip` command from the command line not as a launch from VSC

Answer (score 3):

Step1:- First of all, you need to make sure that autopep8 module is installed in your PC, You can check this by using
`python -m autopep8 --version`
. If you can see the version then you can go to Step 3.

Step2:- You need to install autopep8 using the command line
`pip install --user autopep8`

Step3:- In the command line type `where.exe autopep8` and copy that path to the **Python>Formatting:Autopep8 Path**  which is present in the setting of Autopep8 package.

Comment: Your answer works (on Windows), but you did not clarify **where exactly** you would paste the path. I suggest merging this answer with [@Chen Wang 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61923188/how-to-stop-autopep8-not-installed-messages-in-code#answer-66219550)
1. Go to Python extension's extension setting.
2. Find Python>Formatting:Autopep8 Path term
3. Add the full path of the autopep8 that you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

The [Python extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_install-visual-studio-code-and-the-python-extension) supports us to use Python in VSCode, but we install the module not in the path of the python extension.

We use the module "`autopep8`" in the current [VSCode environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).
Use `pip` to install it in the VSCode terminal:

[image]

check:

[image]